# PIG Apache:How to join 3 tables?

Tags: apache-pig

I want to use inner join to join 3 tables. I can do with 2 tables and get correct result. However, when I tried to join 3 tables I get error

"org.apache.pig.impl.logicalLayer.FrontendException: ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias result2"

this is the code

```html
film = LOAD './film.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (film_id:int);
film_category = LOAD './film_category.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (film_id:int , category_id:int);
category = LOAD './category .csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (category_id:int);

result1 = JOIN film BY film_id , film_category BY film_id , category BY category_id;
result2 = JOIN result1 BY film_category.category_id , category BY category_id;


DUMP result2;
```

### EDIT

I get this message also

Input(s):
Successfully read 1001 records from: "file:///usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/pig/project/film_category.csv"
Successfully read 1001 records from: "file:///usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/pig/project/film.csv"
Failed to read data from "file:///usr/local/hadoop-2.7.2/pig/project/category .csv"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in "file:/tmp/temp623991148/tmp1923149313"

Thank you

Comment: I get the mistake in the code 1) there is space in file name of category. 2) I should use filme_category::category_id instead

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
film = LOAD './film.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (film_id:int);

film_category = LOAD './film_category.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (film_id:int , category_id:int);

category = LOAD './category .csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (category_id:int);

first_join = JOIN film BY film_id , film_category BY film_id;

film_and_film_category = FOREACH first_join GENERATE 
film::film_id AS film_id, film_category::category_id AS category_id;

second_join = JOIN film_and_film_category BY category_id , category BY category_id;

final = FOREACH second_join GENERATE 
film_and_film_category::film_id AS film_id, category::category_id AS category_id;

DUMP final;
```